# Python Logging - Make a log file which list the files that raise an error in For loop

Tags: python, for-loop, logging, error-handling

I am trying some operation in the loop

```
from obspy import read
for file in glob.glob('*.*'):
    st=read(file)
```

But some particular files in the directory can't be read,and it gives some error.
I want to make a log file which lists the filenames(with path) of files which gives me the error using the `logging` module.

I was trying something like open a text file and writing the filename on that ( somehow sometimes I ended up with an empty file even though there was error),

```
f=open('log_response.txt','w')
 
for file in glob.glob('*.*'):
    try:
    # block raising an exception
       st=read(file)
    except:
    #If there is any error write the filename to the file or pass
       f.write('{}\n'.format(os.path.abspath(file)))
       pass
    else:
        print(st)

f.close()
```

But I would like to use the `logging` module
How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(handlers=[logging.FileHandler(filename="log_response.txt",
                                                 encoding='utf-8', mode='a+')],
                    format="%(asctime)s %(name)s:%(levelname)s:%(message)s",
                    datefmt="%F %A %T",
                    level=logging.INFO)



for file in glob.glob('*.*'):
    try:
        st = read(file)
    except:
        logging.error('{}'.format(os.path.abspath(file)))
        pass
```